# Does Django use built in variable names for Templates?

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django and have done some tutorials. Does Django have built in variables that are accessible to any template in any app, or are these defined somewhere in code? For example, I have an app called `users`. In the `models.py` of users/models.py, I have this code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

In `urls.py` I have this:

```
 path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile')
```

In `users/views.py` I do have a function called `profile`, but no where in that function am I passing a variable that allows for the use of obtaining a person's first name, however, in my template `profile.html` I can get the first person's name by using:

```
{{ user.first_name }}
```

Why is this? I was under the impression that we had to pass specific variables as dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the part, where you would have to pass the dictionary from view to the template to access it, yet few things are passed by default one of which is authentication data, the user object.
 This allows you to use functions like 'user.is_authentication' etc for rendering.

The main reason for the variable to pass is to check the JWT authentication in each request coming and going from the server. As you already see the variable is not accessible in the browser because it has been converted into a cookie which you can inspect in the browser.

You can read more here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#built-in-template-context-processors

Comment: Thank you for your response. In order to use {{ user.first_name }} do I have to have "from django.contrib.auth.models import User" in the models.py? Or are these "user" variables able to be used in templates without that line of code?

Comment: You don't need to import the user model unless you want to extend it. You should be able to access user.first_name in the template without any import.

Comment: No problem, to close this question please mark this as the answer.